# Image Button OnClick Event Not firing

Tags: asp.net

Here Is the Code, when i try to fire the event in Browser it is not fired

```html
     <asp:Panel ID="StateDistrictGrid_pnl" runat="server">
         <asp:GridView ID="User_grd" runat="server" DataKeyNames="VoterID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True">
             <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="Img_btn" ImageUrl="~/Images/52105-200.png" OnClick="Img_btn_Click" Height="20px" Width="30px" runat="server" />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" Visible="false" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="VoterName" HeaderText="Voter Name" SortExpression="VoterName" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="StateName" HeaderText="State Name" SortExpression="StateName" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="DistrictName" HeaderText="District Name" SortExpression="DistrictName" />
             </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
         <asp:Label ID="Lbl_Result" runat="server">
             <asp:Button ID="BtnShowPopup" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
             <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="Show_mpe" runat="server" TargetControlID="BtnShowPopup" PopupControlID="PopUp_Pnl" CancelControlID="Btn_Cancel" BackgroundCssClass="textbox_radius"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
             <asp:Panel ID="PopUp_Pnl" runat="server" style = "display:none">
<asp:Label Font-Bold = "true" ID = "Details_lbl" runat = "server" Text = "Voter Details" ></asp:Label>
<br />
<table align = "center">
      <tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID = "ID_lbl" runat = "server" Text = "Voter ID" ></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="VoterID_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>   
</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID = "Voter_lbl" runat = "server" Text = "Voter Name" ></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="VoterName_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>   
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID = "Statepnl_lbl" runat = "server" Text = "State Name" ></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="State_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID = "Districtpnl_lbl" runat = "server" Text = "District Name" ></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="District_txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />
</td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="Btn_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
         </asp:Label>

      </asp:Panel>
```

and the backend code is like this:
is thier any problem in In my Code please help thank you

```
  protected void Img_btn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton Bt = sender as ImageButton;
    GridViewRow GVRow = (GridViewRow)Bt.NamingContainer;
    ID_lbl.Text = User_grd.DataKeys[GVRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    VoterName_txt.Text = GVRow.Cells[2].Text;
    State_txt.Text = GVRow.Cells[3].Text;
    District_txt.Text = GVRow.Cells[4].Text;
}
```

but when i run it the event is not Fired..What's the Problem?

Comment: try putting `alert` and check...

Comment: You can't use a button's normal OnClick event inside a GridView template. You need to subscribe to the OnRowCommand event of your GridView instead. You give your ImageButton a unique CommandName and check for that name in the RowCommand event. Have a look at how to do it here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/564619/Example-of-gridview-rowcommand-on-Button-Click

Comment: Have you placed your code inside update panel?

Comment: no i have not placed a update panel

Comment: I have used above code and it is working, I am able to get the breakpoint in .cs file. I clicked on the image button in first column titled "Edit". There might be some problem in other part of the code, this seems fine.

Comment: @Scotty I don't there is any restriction that you cannot use OnClick event, you can achieve the functionality either way, but generally its a wide practice to use CommandName and handle it in OnRowCommand.

Comment: can anyone post the full code as i am not able to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is somehow the same that I encountered few months back. This might help you some way or another. try using `LinkButton` instead of `Button`...

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:gridview runat="server" id="GridView1" showfooter="true" 
          autogeneratecolumns="false" GridLines="None" CssClass="table1"  
          OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" BorderColor="#356600" 
          BorderStyle="Solid" >
            <columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="Date" runat="server" 
                          CausesValidation="false"   CommandName="Date_Select"  
                          Text='<%#Eval("Date","{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>' onclick="Date_Click"
                          EnableTheming="False"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:boundfield datafield="Profit" headertext="Profit"
                  footerstyle-font-bold="true">
                    <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True"></FooterStyle>
                </asp:boundfield>
            </columns>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CEFF99" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="#C1FF80" 
              BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"></HeaderStyle>
            <RowStyle CssClass="td"></RowStyle>
        </asp:gridview>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```c#
protected void Date_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton Lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
    Label1.Text = Lnk.Text; // This one works for me....
    OdbcConnection con1 = 
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["connect1"]
                .ConnectionString);
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select a.customer As Customer,a.mins as MIns,a.amount as Amount,a.profit as Profit from summarydatashort a,clientsrecord b where a.orig_clli=b.orig_clli and a.date='" + Label1.Text + "' and b.emplye='Ankit'", con1);
    con1.Open();
    OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    con1.Close();
    GridView17.DataSource = ds;
    GridView17.DataBind();
}
```